# O(nlogn) algorithm to find ranges that contain others

Tags: algorithm

If you have n ranges where a range is something like `[1,4.5]`, how can you find if any index contains another in `O(nlogn)` time? Note: `[x,y]` would contain completely `[a,b]` if `x >= a` and `b <= y`.

This seems like it could be done similarly to merge sort where you could check if any ranges contained another in each half of the total amount of ranges and then compare if any range in either half contains a range in the other half.  My problem is that I can't find a `O(n)` way to do this last part. I'm guessing I would somehow have to combine some ranges, but I can't think of how.

Comment: What should be the output of the algorithm? Is it just `true`/`false`, indicating whether *at least one* range contains another range? Or do you need to return a mapping of which range contains which?

Comment: Just true / false is sufficient. We do not need to know what the two ranges are even

Comment: Your definition of `contain` looks to me more like a partial overlapping, am I wrong?

Comment: I mean complete overlapping. So [1,5] would contain [2,3] but not [3,6]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a simple algorithm which appears to operate in `O(nlogn)` time:

First *sort* the set of `n` ranges using the *beginning* value of the range, from smallest to largest.  If you use merge sort here, this should run in `O(nlogn)` time.  As @Aivean pointed out, there is one edge case to consider when two or more ranges have equal beginning values.  In this case, such ranges should be ordered by their range ending value in *descending* order.

Next walk along this set of ranges from smallest first value to highest, and do the following:

```
for (range r : ranges[1 to N-1]) {
    if (end value for range r+1 <= end value for range r) {
        // then range r+1 is completely contained within some previous range
        return true;
    }
}
```

This second step is a single `O(n)` pass, which won't change the overall `O(nlogn)` running time from the first step.

Here is a graphical illustration showing you how the algorithm would work.  The ranges have been sorted using the *beginning* value of the range, from smallest to largest.  It should be clear that all that is necessary is to walk from left to right and compare the *ending* values of each pair of ranges, in sequence.

```
1. |------|
2.  |-------|
3.    |-------|
4.    |------|
5.              |-------|
6.                  |-------|
```

Appreciate that when checking range #3 we *don't* need to check anything beyond range #2.  The reason for this is that in order for range #1 to contain range #3, it would have to extend *beyond* range #2, which would imply that it *already* contains range #2.  But this means the algorithm would have already returned true, so we don't need to check for this possibility.

Also note that ranges #3 and #4 are sorted in descending order by their ending values.  This ensures that the algorithm will detect that range #4 is completely contained within range #3.  You can reverse the order of ranges #3 and #4 to see how there might be a problem in the case of a tie in starting values.

Comment: So in the second step, you are only comparing adjacent ranges? This doesn't account for the fact that even if range `r` does not include `r+1`, it could still contain `r+2`.

Comment: wait, is the algorithm really correct? what about `[1, 5], [2, 6], [3, 4]?`

Comment: I think this answer would still work. If `r+2` is in range `r`, then `r+2` would have to be in `r+1` as `r+1` has a lower or equal to lower bound from the sort and its upper bound should always be above the upper bound of `r+2` then.

Comment: @DjSledgehammer look at the example provided by svs.

Comment: But [3,4] is in [2,6] so this algorithm would still catch that as the endpoint of `r+2` is 4 which is <= the endpoint of `r+1` which is 6

Comment: Wow, the initial solution actually works! @Tim, it was a nice idea with having a max right boundary. But as Dj pointed, it's not even required.

Comment: @DmytroShevchenko Yes I also just realized this.  The reason you don't need to max boundary condition is that if the `rth` range is _not_ contained in the range before it, it _also_ won't be contained in any prior range since that would have already returned true at that point (having found an earlier match).

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis This case is irrelevant because the algorithm would _already_ have returned `true` upon hitting `[2, 3]`.  Please remove your downvote thanks.

Comment: this answer does not account ranges with equal left boundaries. Example: `[1,2] ,[1,4]`. Easy fix will be to modify sort to break ties by right boundary when comparing elements with equal left boundaries. Right boundaries should be in descending order: `[1,4], [1,3], [1,2]`.

Comment: @Aivean Very nice catch.  I have updated my answer to explicitly mention this during the sorting process.